# What is the import path for @EnableAuthorizationServer annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I am trying to make sense of Spring Authorization Server.

Following various tutorials, and the original documentation, pretty much the first step after configuring dependencies –

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.2.1'
//  other db/test stuff
}
```

– is to add the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation to the main class.

Except my IDE (NetBeans) doesn't have a clue, from the imports, what that refers to.

So: what's the import path supposed to be for `@EnableAuthorizationServer`? (And, logically, is there some other dependency needed that to have it recognised?)

Comment: The dependencies are not the "*import paths*". - The import path is [`org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableAuthorizationServer.html).

Comment: `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is deprecated and not available in any of your included dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new Spring Authorization Server, you don't need the `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. This annotation is from the old `spring-security-oauth` module, which [is deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth).

The key is the `SecurityFilterChain`, which should have a higher precedence, like so:

```java
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
}
```

I recommend you to take a look at [the samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample) in the official repository.

Comment: If only the sample were accessible… (within an IDE)

Comment: What do you mean? You can clone the repo and test it. There is another sample in the Spring Security Samples repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/authorization-server

Comment: I can download it. I can't test it because there's basically nothing to run; I can only get to its contents via the Files view; in Projects, it shows three build scripts and an empty Sub Projects folder. Accessing via Files, import statements aren't properly parsed, I assume because it's not being seen as a project so doesn't know where to look for the referenced file.

Comment: You are supposed to run the `main` methods. You should clone the whole repo and not only the samples to make it work

Comment: I did. I described what I get opening the whole project (spring-authorization-server-main) in Netbeans. Nothing runnable.

Comment: The project's build.gradle may not be functional in Netbeans. There's also a standalone sample for [Spring Authorization Server in spring-security-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/authorization-server).